# Значення/ вживання слів синонімів змушений, вимушений, примушений?

Tags: вживання-слів

Згідно усіх словників слова "вимушений, змушений, примушений" є синонімами. Але вживати їх як синоніми іноді  не зовсім виходить правильно.
У цих варіантах вживаються слова з різним значенням, але їх можна замінити між собою!?

1. “Гірке почуття вимушеної розлуки з сином запанувало всім його тілом (Г.Епік).”
2. “Змушений жити в місті, далеко од народу, я часом з головою пірнаю в етнографічні записи (М.Коцюбинський). “
3. “Була б якась потіха мені з того, якби ти заїхала, я б, може, чогось довідалась, що вивело б мене з сеї примушеної пасивності (Леся Українка).”

Я не бачу в них різниці навіть після перестановки...
Хоча [на сайті «Словопедія»](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53394/30298.html) і на багатьох інших сайтах пишеться про їх різне значення...?

Answer (score 3):

По-перше, саме на [словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53394/30298.html) після опису значення слів "вимушений" і "примушений" пише, що це те саме, що "змушений", якщо слово вживається як дієприкметник:

> **Вимушений**. 1. Дієприкм. від вимусити; **змушений**: вимушений був піти
>   на заробітки; війська вимушені зайняти оборону. **2. прикм.** Який
>   здійснюється чи здійснений проти бажання, потреби, під тиском
>   обставин: вимушена зупинка, вимушене неробство, вимушене сидіння.
>   Гірке почуття вимушеної розлуки з сином запанувало всім його тілом
>   (Г.Епік). **3. прикм.** Здійснюваний через силу; роблений, нещирий:
>   вимушений спокій, вимушений усміх, вимушена увага, вимушені рухи.
>
> **Змушений**. Дієприкм. від змусити; який мусить, повинен через певні
>   обставини, причини робити щось: змушені були відступити, змушені
>   зупинитись, змушені працювати. Змушений жити в місті, далеко од
>   народу, я часом з головою пірнаю в етнографічні записи
>   (М.Коцюбинський).
>
> **Примушений**. Дієприкм. від примусити – присилувати
>   робити саме так; **змушений**: примушений був піти з роботи,
>   примушений відмовитись від прогулянки. Була б якась потіха мені з
>   того, якби ти заїхала, я б, може, чогось довідалась, що вивело б мене
>   з сеї примушеної пасивності (Леся Українка).

По-друге, у вашому випадку у виразі "вимушена розлука" слово "вимушена" - це прикметник (друге значення слова "вимушений" на словопедії), розлука не може бути змушена або примушена (через дієприкметники), бо розлуку не можна змусити, примусити, вимусити щось робити, вона може бути тільки вимушена (через прикметник), тобто, така, яка "здійснюється чи здійснена проти бажання, потреби, під тиском обставин".

У виразі Лесі Українки "примушена пасивність", бо "примушений" використовується у ось якому [значенні](http://sum.in.ua/s/prymushenyj): "який склався в певних обставинах; вимушений.", тобто, так само, як прикметник.

Тобто, у більшості випадків це взаємозамінні слова, просто треба зважати на частини мови.